# How can I avoid unnecessary concurrency exceptions in my EF 6 scenario?

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-6, n-tier-architecture

I am using EF 6. I have a two tier application using WCF Soap and DTOs to transfer data. I send an object graph across the wire for the user to update, and then send it back to persist the changes. In between, I use AutoMapper to convert to and from DTOs and entities.

On the persistence side, I receive my DTO and unpack it (it contains lists of entities). I unpack it into the appropriate entities and check whether we are adding or editing by checking if the id is 0. So far I have just blindly updated every entity whose id > 0.

However, I have learned this is not the best way because it throws unnecessary concurrency exceptions. If I just call update on the entity, the rowversion gets updated, even if no fields actually changed values in the database. This is causing unnecessary concurrency exceptions. I need to avoid these. So I need to somehow check to see if an entity really needs to be updated or not. The only way I know how to check whether an entity needs to be updated, is to query the database and do a property by property check.

My question: Am I on the right track? Do I in fact really need to check an entity property by property to find out if it needs to be updated? Is there an easier or more automatic way?

I feel frustrated by the need to query the database for each entity before saving changes. Maybe I am missing something?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var ws = saveRequest.Workspace;
var td = saveRequest.ToDelete;

using (var db = new EngineeringContext())
{
    var ass = Attach<JobAssembly>(db, db.JobAssemblies, ws.Assemblies.ToDomain());
    var opr = Attach<JobOperation>(db, db.JobOperations, ws.Operations.ToDomain());
    var mtl = Attach<JobMaterial>(db, db.JobMaterials, ws.Materials.ToDomain());

    Delete<JobAssembly>(db, td.Assemblies.ToDomain());
    Delete<JobOperation>(db, td.Operations.ToDomain());
    Delete<JobMaterial>(db, td.Materials.ToDomain());

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Sync Error: The data failed to save due to changes by another user.", ex);
    }

    ws.Assemblies = ass.ToDto();
    ws.Operations = opr.ToDto();
    ws.Materials = mtl.ToDto();
}
```

Where Attach and Delete look something like this:

```
db.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; // .Deleted for deletes.
```

And ToDomain and ToDto are extensions that map domains (entities) to dtos and viceversa.

Comment: Hard to tell what to fix if you don't show what you're doing.  e.g. are you using `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: I added the code where the save and the exception occur.

Comment: You either have to query the database or the entities must have some mechanism to track changes themselves. There used to be self-tracking entities in EF, but they were deprecated.